# No matching function for call to 'std::advance' error

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code which `Xcode` says it doesn't recognised the signature for `std::advance`:

```
template<typename Container> const typename Container::value_type&
getNthElement(const Container& container, size_t n) {
    auto nElem = advance(container.begin(), n);
    return *nElem;
}
```

The compiler doesn't support `C++14` so I can't use `cbegin(container)`. Why is this solution wrong ?

Comment: Have you included `<iterator>` ?

Comment: `std::advance` modifies its (first) argument and does not return anything. `begin()` probably returns a prvalue, which cannot bind to reference parameter of `advance`. Use `std::next` instead.

Comment: `std::advanced` requires a non-const argument. The iterator you are passing is a `const_iterator`. Why don't you use `std::next`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `advance` does not modify the element, it modifies the iterator. (à la `int const* p = ..; ++p;`)

Comment: @dyp I never said it modifies the element.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Hm. Then, why is it important that a `const_iterator` is used?

Comment: @dyp Wouldn't the iterator itself be `const` and therefore modifying it through `advance` fail?

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, that's not how `const_iterators` work. They are non-const iterators to const things. The problem is the rvalue binding to an lvalue reference. Plus the fact that `advance` is a `void` function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Which iterator? The one returned by `.begin()`? It'll probably be a non-const prvalue, though I had to look up what the spec actually requires (edit: container requirements say `begin()` returns a `const_iterator` in this case, by value). A plain old `const_iterator` is an abstraction of a const pointer, hence itself modifiable.

Comment: Too bad there isn't an answer in the answer space.  There is clearly one in the comment space.

Comment: So instead of advance I used next, so someone should provide this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::advance` doesn't return anything (see here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/, its return type is `void`) so `auto nElem = advance(container.begin(), n);` isn't valid.
As said in comments, you can use next. :)